# calculate statistics for every column and add it to empty Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

my idea is to get statistics like mean,median,var,min,max from every column of a dataframe and save it to a new empty dataframe. My dataframe looks like this:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   3   4   2   1
1   4   3   3   1
2   4   2   3   0
```

and my new dataframe should look like this:

```
A_mean | A_median | A_var | A_max | A_min | B_mean | B_median | B_var | B_max  |B_min | ...
 1          2         1       1       0      1           1        1       2       1     ...
```

i can't use df.describe() because it doesn't have var or median.

My idea of implementing this:

```
row=pd.DataFrame()
for column in df:
        row = row.append({column + '_mean':df_test[column].mean()}, ignore_index=True) 
        row = row.append({column + '_median':df_test[column].median()}, ignore_index=True)
        row = row.append({column + '_var':df_test[column].var()}, ignore_index=True)
        row = row.append({column + '_max':df_test[column].max()}, ignore_index=True)
        row = row.append({column + '_min':df_test[column].min()}, ignore_index=True)
```

but then i get

[image]

my goal is to have this in one row not in 10 different rows. How could I change my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible change format use [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) with functions in list:

```
df = df.agg(['mean','median', 'var','max','min'])
print (df)
               A    B         C         D
mean    3.666667  3.0  2.666667  0.666667
median  4.000000  3.0  3.000000  1.000000
var     0.333333  1.0  0.333333  0.333333
max     4.000000  4.0  3.000000  1.000000
min     3.000000  2.0  2.000000  0.000000
```

Or add [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and transpose, last flatten columns names for one row `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.agg(['mean','median', 'var','max','min']).unstack().to_frame().T
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df)
     A_mean  A_median     A_var  A_max  A_min  B_mean  B_median  B_var  B_max  \
0  3.666667       4.0  0.333333    4.0    3.0     3.0       3.0    1.0    4.0   

   B_min    C_mean  C_median     C_var  C_max  C_min    D_mean  D_median  \
0    2.0  2.666667       3.0  0.333333    3.0    2.0  0.666667       1.0   

      D_var  D_max  D_min  
0  0.333333    1.0    0.0
```

Comment: hey @jezrael is there any possibility to choose only A and B to build the mean,median,var,max,min?